# How to pass an array of mat4 as a uniform

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, glm-math, uniform

I have to pass an array of mat4 as a uniform to my vertex shader like this:

in the vertex shader:

```
uniform mat4 u_jointMatrix[2];
```

in my C++ program I did like this:

```
glm::mat4 jointM[2];
//I filled jointM with 32 values (16 x 2)
int jointMatrixLoc = glGetUniformLocation(programT, "u_jointMatrix");
glUniformMatrix4fv(jointMatrixLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(jointM[2]));
```

I wrote this because `glUniformMatrix4fv(jointMatrixLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(jointM));` doesn’t work.

I think what I did is incorrect. can someone confirm it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jointM[2]` address the 3rd element in an array with 2 elements. You have to specify a pointer to the first element:

<s>`glUniformMatrix4fv(jointMatrixLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(jointM[2]));`</s>

```cpp
glUniformMatrix4fv(jointMatrixLoc, 2, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(jointM[0]));
```

Comment: Thanks and I don't have to change 1 to 2?